# Is there a performance impact in using _config.GetSection("section")["key"]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, appsettings, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using claims based authorization in my asp.net core 2.0 app and rather than hard coding the claim names throughout my app, I'm thinking about setting them in the injected config object (appsettings.json).

But before I dive down that road, I was curious if there is a performance concern to be aware of?

Something like this:

```
var subscriptionClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == _config.GetSection("ClaimNames")["BasicMembership"]);
```

Versus something like this:

```
var subscriptionClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "basicMembership");
```

I have, at this point, 4-5 claims that I'm adding/removing from users at various points in my app. The reason for rolling the names into appsettings is to make sure I don't typo the claim name, and if for whatever reason in the future I can change them more easily.

But if `_config.GetSection("section")["key"]);` has a noticeable performance hit, I'd rather not. I'm leaning toward not a noticeable perf hit, but I wanted to be sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: best way to find out is to check for yourself .. nothing beats finding out and proving it to yourself

Comment: The best would be to have a wrapper class around configuration. Make it static so that it will retrieve config data from file only once and keep it. And use that wrapper class wherever you want the config values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `_config` an `IConfiguration` object?

Usually you build your configuration object in your application startup, and this information gets loaded into memory, so yes, the performance difference is negligible, at best.

But as others stated, if performance is a concern there is no better way than test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. It is an IConfiguration object the is built in the startup -- automatically now as it's an asp.net core 2.0 app.